# Создание меток программно

Tags: php, wordpress

Допустим имеется массив меток:

```
array('name1'=>'metka1', 'name2'=>'metka2', 'name3'=>'metka1')...
```

ключ это название записи, а значение соответственно метка, которую нужно присвоить данной записи по имени.
Т.е. нужно сначала создать программно новые метки из массива, потом присвоить эти метки записям, которые соответствуют этим меткам в массиве.
Как это реализовать?

Comment: что? что вы хотите сделать, конкретно?

Comment: @Руслан, хочу создать метки и присвоить существующим записям эти созданные метки, по ключу, т.е. ключ это название записи, а значение это метка, которую нужно присвоить этой записи. Рубрики не нужно назначать для записей
http://prntscr.com/ezgc02

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код для решения задачи такой:

```
$tags_arr = array('name1'=>'metka1', 'name2'=>'metka2', 'name3'=>'metka1');
foreach ($tags_arr as $key=>$value) {
    $post = get_page_by_title( $key, OBJECT, array('post') ); // найти запись по названию
    if ($post) {
        $append = true; // true означает добавить метки к существующим
        wp_set_post_tags($post->ID, $value, $append);   // добавить метки к посту
    }
}
```